# Role reactions Discord.js v11

Tags: discord.js

i would like to create a reaction role function to my bot (there IS a message, then if any member reacts to the message, he gets a role. Like in MEE6).
I've tried this...

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (messageReaction, user) => { if(user.bot) return; const { message, emoji } = messageReaction; if(emoji.name === "✅") { if(message.id === "713071578174193745") { 
  var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Nem hitelesített 2")
  user.addRole(role)
  var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Nem hitelesített 1")
  user.removeRole(role)
}}},)
```

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
  console.log("1");
  if (reaction.message.channel.id !== "713066051969220631" && reaction.emoji.name !== '✅') {
    return;
  }
  client.guilds.get(yourguildid).member(user).addRole('713065834771120172')
}
```

but i didn't reach anything. Can you help me please?
Note: I'm on v11. By another man, it worked, he was on v11 too. The ÍTRIGGER isn't working, if i put console.log before if, and i'm reacting, no answer.

Comment: Always have your code in your question, don't send it through links/images

Comment: On your second code paragraph you never added ); on the end of the } that closes the anon function. On your first code bracket I'm not sure why there is a ,) at the end of your code. Shouldn't there be a ; at the very end of ,) as well? And no , there either?

Comment: Just don't use v11, it just makes everything more complicated instead of improving it.